# Unity's 'Vector3.Slerp' equivalent in Unreal Engine 4 C++?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Does UE4 C++ has a built-in function similar to [`Vector3.Slerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Slerp.html)?

If not is there an 'Unreal optimized way' to do that?
I got 2 vectors that I want to get some locations between them on a circular arc path.

Comment: Is that is what you're looking for? https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Math/FQuat/Slerp/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would implement the vector slerp equation ([see wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp)) like so:

```
static FVector Slerp(const FVector& a, const FVector& b, const float t)
{
    float omega = FGenericPlatformMath::Acos(FVector::DotProduct(
            a.GetSafeNormal(), 
            b.GetSafeNormal()
            ));
    float sinOmega = FGenericPlatformMath::Sin(omega);
    FVector termOne = a * (FGenericPlatformMath::Sin(omega * (1.0 - t)) / sinOmega);
    FVector termTwo = b * (FGenericPlatformMath::Sin(omega * (      t)) / sinOmega);
    return termOne + termTwo;
}
```